# How do i add dynamic dropdownlist to a table created by codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I want to build a web page using asp c# which has 4 Cells Labeled "MachineName (Label), Owner (Dropdownlist), Release(dropdownlist with default values of Yes/No), Comments (Textbox)".

Content of the table is loaded from SQLServerDB.

1. In each cell it shows records for one Machine.

2. Owner is dropdownlist, which consist names list from SQLTable (ADuser) of 500 users. But by default it show the current owner of this machine fetched from SQLServer Table (inventory) from which we are getting machine names.

3. Release is simple dropdownlist with default values "Yes/No".

4. Comments is just Textbox.

5. Update/Submit button to update the record column.

I am trying to put all these in simple line. Machine name is static which cannot be edited, Dropdown, Release and comments should be editable and finally with Submit/link button at the end of the Columns to update the particular record only.

I tried by creating Grid, but in grid we get DELETE/EDIT/UPDATE button options.
Tried by creating Placeholder and generating and filling data using htmlappend option. But this way, i am not able to add/bind dropdownlist dynamically.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: c# and asp-classic are mutually exclusive. Which is it?

Comment: They probably mean asp.net